# Is it possible to convert a command line application to an application bundle under OSX

Tags: python, macos, bundle

For some reasons (such as I need to run GUI related code inside a embedding python interpreter [mac osx does not allow me to run any GUI python scripts in an embedding python interpreter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33293428/mac-osx-does-not-allow-me-to-run-any-gui-python-scripts-in-an-embedding-python-i), but OSX does not allow me to do that, unless the application is an application bundle), so I need to convert a command line application to an OSX application bundle.

I see that there exist some script which can convert a bash script to an application bundle, see: [How to create simple Mac apps from shell scripts · Mathias Bynens](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/shell-script-mac-apps).

But I don't see there is any tool to make such translation, any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean this? https://gist.github.com/mathiasbynens/674099

Comment: Oh, your link is try to convert a shell script to an application bundle, but what I want it try to convert a command line application, such as I build a GDB, and I would like to convert it to an application bundle. So that I can run GUI python related code inside the GDB.

Answer (score 0):

1) Write your command line in a text file (choose a filename without extension), then give it executable permissions: type in a terminal:

```
chmod 777 filename
```

It's ready, just double-click on it !

Eventually, if it fails to launch the terminal, you may via the right click menu select the terminal to open it, or change the way it opens in the getinfo.

2) Alternatively, If your command line is just the name of a binary executable program (without command line parameters): just add the extension .app to your program filename. It will run on double click.